# Error handling in a php loop executing mySql

Tags: php, mysql, loops, error-handling

I have a php loop that executes a mySQL query for each cycle of the loop. Right now my loop is hitting a mySql error and stopping. How do I set it up so when it hits a mySql error it just stops what it's doing and moves on to the next loop?

I have added the code below. Please keep in mind I am not trying to solve the SQL error but rather tell the php loop to skip over it.

```
   foreach ($queryData as $value) { 
       mysql_query(" PREPARE stmt FROM 'INSERT INTO `table_name`( `column_name`) VALUES   ('value'  )'EXECUTE stmt1"
                   )or die("die message");
                                  }
```

Comment: Show us the code that generates the error.  Why don't you just fix the error?

Comment: You could throw an [exception](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp)

Comment: You'd get more productive help if you actually shared the code and query in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to halt upon execution, just omit the `die`.

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if ($res) {
 /* do stuff with the query results */
} else {
  /* output an error if desired... or don't */
  echo 'There was a database error: '.mysql_error();
}
```